# Formatting output to a fixed precision in Python

Tags: python

I would like to have always 5 numbers after coma.

Example : 
My data is like 105.56565  105. 165.54......

I want the same length like this: 105.56565 105.00000 165.54000....

script :

```
from pylab import*
from rtlsdr import*
from bluetooth import*
import sys

#configure device
sdr= RtlSdr()
sdr.sample_rate=double(sys.argv[3])
sdr.gain=double(sys.argv[2])
sdr.center_freq=double(sys.argv[1])

#Bluetooth connection

server_sock=BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port=server_sock.getsockname()[1]
uuid="94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"
client_sock,client_info=server_sock.accept()

while(1):
        samples=sdr.read_samples(256*1024)
        result=psd(samples,NFFT=1024, Fs=sdr.sample_rate/1e6, Fc=sdr.center_freq*1e6/1e6)
        freq=result[1]/1e6
        value_freq=str(freq)[1:-1]
        print format(freq, '%5f') // he do not work
```

Answer (score 1):

On that last line, I think you want to do:

```
print "%5f" % freq
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The format language used by the `format` builtin (and `str.format`) is not quite the same as the `printf` style formatting used by the `%` operator. You should [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) for the details on the language.

For your specific case, I suspect you want `format(freq, ".5f")`. This will always give your five digits after the decimal point.

Comment: i did this : `tab_freq=(result[]/1e6)  tab_freq_convert=str(tab_freq)[1:-1]  value_freq=format(tab_freq_convert, ".5f")` but I have always the same error : `Unknow format code 'f' for object of type 'str`